# Filter articles by category with Nesta CMS

Tags: nestacms

We want to display article summaries for a given category.

Standard index page is build like this:

```
%section.articles= article_summaries(latest_articles)
```

but I see no way of filtering articles by category.

Answer (score 3):

OK figured it out-
To list articles by category, you have to assign pages to a given category AND create an actual category page for each category- i.e. a page named the same as the category.

For example, if my page is assigned to categories **dogs** and **cats**...

```
Categories: dogs, cats
```

I'll need to create new pages called **dogs.haml** and **cats.haml**, which will then list the articles for those categories with the standard code found in the default page.haml template:

```
%section.articles
  = article_summaries(@page.articles)
```